# How to make lf file-manager to show only one file types?

Tags: files, terminal, file-manager

**Basically what I want**:
When I browse files/dires with [lf](https://github.com/gokcehan/lf), I want to toggle "something" on the way. And only see PDF files, and make invisible any other file-types.

**Rationale**: Sometimes it's bit annoying to search certain file(s) that I forgot the filename but remember the file-type. Especially in a large directory which consists of varies files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, I just found it.

Apparently `:filter .pdf` would filter files that contains `.pdf`.

Comment: additionally, this filtering can be mapped to `Alt`-`f` with `map <a-f> filter` in the config file

Answer (score 1):

You could use `:set sortby ext`. This sorts the files based on their extension. This way you'd have all the files of a certain filetype grouped together.

Comment: Thanks, this is also useful to remember.